# Loop over tif-files in a folder but excluding tif.aux files in R

Tags: r, file, loops, directory

I want to loop through all .TIF files in a folder and process them with a function. While looping through the files I have the problem, that my looping function does not only use .TIF-files, but also TIF.aux.xml, TIF.xml and TIF.ovr. As soon as I want to process them in my loop the loop stops because my processing can only done with the real TIF files. When I tried to use the regular expression '*.tif' it does not recognize any file, when I use '*.TIF' it recognizes each single file including 'TIF.aux.xml', 'TIF.xml' and 'TIF.ovr'. There must be a trick with regular expressions to prevent that and make the expression stop after the F. Does anyone have an idea how to work around?

The code I use (the function does not matter so far... it's just about the regular expression I guess):

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

files <- list.files(input_dir, pattern = '*.TIF', full.names = TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  file_name <- files[i]
  file_raster <- brick(paste(input_dir), files[i], sep="")
  # function...
}
```

Comment: Try `pattern = '\\.TIF$'`. See also `?glob2rx`

Comment: Both your solutions work out fine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tools)
files <- list_files_with_exts(input_dir, "tif")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case "tif" still had to be "TIF"